# Xubuntu WiFi Button missing from Panel 0 / Panel settings

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

So I have a PC running only Xubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I just install real VNC's VNC viewer - to access my Raspberry PI remotely. The second time I restarted, the WiFi button disappeared from panel 0 (task bar). I don't think I installed any other software recently before the problem. I had also made a c++ code that gave the error `Floating point exception (core dumped)` when I run it. The code is compiling normal. The PC is an HP notebook 15.

edit: I can access the internet via auto connect, I can't select the network.

edit: I took one last try at fixing it and now my wifi button, discord button, and dropbox buttons are back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have an indicator plugin, a notification plugin, and a status notifier plugin. If any of these are missing, add them.